# Upload files Google drive api filename Untitled?

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Drive api uploads file name as “Untitled”

code
 [1]：https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeGFh.jpg

```
function uploadPostFile(selectedFile){  
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name={
        "name":"xxx"
    }
    oReq.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8; boundary=foo_bar_baz;');
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',name);
    //get token                                           
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token);
    //send file object
    oReq.send(selectedFile);
}
```

Comment: That is not how the API works, the JSON with the `name` has to be part of the request's body not the header. Take a look at the example in the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#send_a_multipart_upload_request)

Comment: Can you provide a sample code?